# What is BusinessExtensionsWrapper app on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, security

I noticed an app with the name **BusinessExtensionsWrapper** under Settings > Mobile Data.
It is not visible on the Home Screen or via search. [This link](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki//Applications) lists it to be a native app but Apple Support says it is a third-party app and resetting iPhone would help, but it didn't.

**More info:**

1. I turned off Mobile Data for it and incidentally while opening a business message on iMessage, there was a pop-up saying mobile data for "BusinessExtensionsWrapper" was turned off. The pop-up had option to go to Settings to turn it on
2. iPhone model's region is Japan
3. iPhone model is 12 Pro running iOS 14.7.1
4. No such app is found on App Store
5. The device is not jailbroken or company owned

It would be useful if someone can help me understand what this app does and why is it the only app extension that is visible to the user?

Comment: Is this a jailbroken or company-owned device?

Comment: @fsb oh it is an important piece of information I forgot to mention, no it is neither of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BusinessExtensionsWrapper is a first-party app built into iOS since iOS 11 (`/Applications/BusinessExtensionsWrapper.app`).

Its bundle ID is `com.apple.icloud.apps.messages.business`, indicating its purpose is to support [Business Chat](https://www.apple.com/ios/business-chat/).

Comment: thanks for the answer! I tried to find out if other people around me had this app on their devices and the result was negative! How to explain this?

Comment: @DDC It's used as part of Messages, so it doesn't show as a separate app.

Comment: Right but why just on my phone that’s the question! I mean I obviously checked on other device’s mobile data settings too!

Comment: @DDC It will be on everyone’s phone being part of iOS, but apps only show in the Mobile Data list after using some amount of data.

Comment: Ah! That’s the point I missed!!